# Declaring variable inside and outside of @implementation

Tags: objective-c

I am just trying to understand life of variables with a throw away below code. I can see _inside and _outside retains when about instantiate new instance, while braces are not.

```
@interface ViewController (){
    NSString *_innBraces;
}

@end

NSString *_outside;

@implementation ViewController{
    NSString *_inmBraces;
}

NSString *_inside;

-(id)initWithInside:(NSString*)inside outside:(NSString*)outside nBraces:(NSString*)nBraces mBraces:(NSString*)mBraces{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _inside = inside;
        _outside = outside;
        _innBraces = nBraces;
        _inmBraces = mBraces;
        return self;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

1. Is there any difference between the place of declaration of _inside and _outside?
2. Any difference between braces variables from where it is declared?
3. Any difference between static variable declared same way vs _inside/_outside variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `_inside` and `_outside` are both declared as global variables.
2. Since you appear to be declaring everything in the same file, there's no difference between `_innBraces` and `_inmBraces`, they are both instance variables in the class.  If the `@interface` were in a header file, then you'd see a difference in scope between the two, since the `_inmBraces` would only be visible in your implementation file, and `_innBraces` will be visible in any file that includes the `.h` file.
3. Neither of these are declared static.   If they had been (preceding with the `static` keyword), then they would each be local in storage and namespace to the file where they are declared.

In the case of 1 and 3, they are both straight C declarations, and thus whether they are in the scope of the `@implementation` and `@interface` is doesn't make any difference.   In Objective-C, there are no class variables, as such.

For class variables, the general process is to create a file-static variable of the form:

```
static NSString *sMyClassVariable;
```

within the implementation file.   This variable, because it is static, will not be visible in any other file than your implementation file.

Comment: i am not sure about `_inside`, it cant be accessed outside the class

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yes it can.  It's just a C variable with global scope.

Comment: @gaige, Can you please explain for #2 comment additionally what scope it will get when declared in .h file? And also can you elaborate #3 please? Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyP: But it is in .m ? AS you can see my answer, i got confused so i deleted mine one.